# No GPG agent running on CentOS 7

Tags: gnupg, password-management

I have a git-enabled password archive with the little program pass. I can clone it to a Linux Mint notebook, a CentOS 7 virtual machine and even a Mac OS X system and the password decryption with GPG just works.

However, on my CentOS 7 machine I get the following error messages when trying to decrypt a password with GPG by requesting e.g.:

```
pass other/github

gpg: can't connect to the agent: IPC connect call failed

gpg: problem with the agent: No agent running

gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
```

So far I tried importing the GPG keys to the CentOS 7 machine.

Comment: Please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1113411/edit) the question and include the commands you execute. Those that complete successfully on Mint and OS X and fail on CentOS.

Answer (score 0):

So I started once again fresh. I deleted all gpg keys so that gpg --list-keys and gpg --list-private-keys return no output. Then I imported my keys again, this time by my KDE GUI. At that time also KGpg was configured.
So now gpg --list-keys returns the following output:

> pub   2048R/DBD99EE2 2016-04-24
>
> uid            Patrick (password storage pass) <\mymail@mail.com>
>
> sub   2048R/C1F1B351 2016-04-24

and --list-secret-keys returns:

> sec   2048R/DBD99EE2 2016-04-24
>
> uid                  Patrick  (password storage pass) <\mymail@mail.com>
>
> ssb   2048R/C1F1B351 2016-04-24

Then when I want to access some password stored with pass by e.g. pass other/github the messages returned are still:

> gpg: can't connect to the agent: IPC connect call failed
>
> gpg: problem with the agent: No agent running
>
> gpg: decryption failed: No secret key

Thank you.

Patrick